# in python how can i recursively replace % placeholders in a string

Tags: python-2.7

I have a large block of python code which builds an SQL query.  It does this by calling several other functions to get parts of the query and then assembles them.  I am trying to figure out how to output a string that is the MySQL query that is actually run.

I don't want to show all of the actual code (because there is a lot of it) and also I don't know python very well but here is my attempt at showing what this code does:

```
import random

def myClause():
  if (random.randint(1,101) > 50):
    clause_part = 10;
  else
    clause_part = 500;
  clause = "WHERE table2.id > %(clause_part)s
  return clause

def doQuery():
  clause = myClause();
  if (random.randint(1,101) > 50):
    other_clause_part = 10;
  else
    other_clause_part = 500;
  my_sql = """SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.t2_id = table2.id
     WHERE table1.id > %(other_clause_part)s
     %(clause)s""" % {'other_clause_part': other_clause_part,
                      'clause': clause}

  print(my_sql)
  cur.execute(my_sql)
```

It's something like this (yea i know, i'm sure there are some sort of python bugs in this code, again, i don't know python).  The thing that is happening is when i see the result printed out, it only evaluates the 'other_clause_part' and does not evaluate the 'clause'.  I presume it is because the placeholders that are replaced only go one level deep.  In otherwords I have placeholders and I also have placeholders which themselves have placeholders.  Is there any way to recursively replace all of the placeholders in a string and then print out the output somewhere?

Comment: If you're just looking for `printf` functionality, [Python has that](https://pyformat.info/), e.g. `"%s %s" % ("one", "two") == "one two"`

Comment: But isn't that already being done in this example?

Comment: The syntax matters. You'll see the substitution once you correct your string formatting to match the expected syntax. I don't think recursion is part of your question, unless I'm severely misunderstanding what you're asking.

Comment: The whole idea of using string substitution like this to construct SQL statements seems wrong to begin with. Why aren't you using something like SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I totally agree.  unfortunately this is some archaic 10 year old code base that I didn't write.  If it were up to me i'd toss this whole pile of crap and rewrite it in PHP with Laravel and Eloquent.  Nevertheless this is not an option for me given the time I have to fix it.

Comment: @DallasCaley Thanks for the explanation. Just wanted to make sure it's not a beginner gone off in a totally wrong direction. (Well, maybe it was, but 10 years ago.)

Comment: Now that I'm reading your question more closely -- it looks like the problem is that `clause` is _also_ a format string. That is, it _is_ doing the substitution, but the substituted value contains additional formatting placeholders. It's not clear from your question what the value that's supposed to replace those should be, at least to me.

Comment: I think i figured it out. i'll post here in a minute...

Comment: Basically it looks like your last line under the `WHERE` statement, where you have `'%(clause)s' % {'clause': clause}` should be `'%(clause)s % {'clause': clause % {'clause_part': some_other_value}}`

Comment: So it's really just a question of whether or not you need actual recursion to go an unknown number of steps down replacing formatters, or just format more manually. Seems easier to me (guessing through the snippet) to pass `clause_part` into `myClause()` and return it all the way formatted.

Answer (score 1):

So, first I had to learn a bit more python and make my example actually work.  This led me to the following:

```
import random

def myClause():
  if (random.randint(1,101) > 50):
    clause_part = 10
  else:
    clause_part = 500
  clause = "WHERE table2.id > %(clause_part)s"
  return clause

def doQuery():
  clause = myClause()
  if (random.randint(1,101) > 50):
    other_clause_part = 10
  else:
    other_clause_part = 500
  my_sql = """SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.t2_id = table2.id
    WHERE table1.id > 1 %(other_clause_part)s
    %(clause)s""" % {'other_clause_part': other_clause_part,
                     'clause': clause}

  my_sql2 = my_sql % {'clause_part': 'whatever'}

  print(my_sql2)

doQuery()
```

The original thing I was trying to do was not possible because the placeholder in the first string was replaced with another placeholder.  also the placeholder for the second string was not in the data object that was used to replace the placeholders.   (sorry this isn't sounding right so i'll explain with examples)  After the first replacement my string looked like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.t2_id = table2.id
    WHERE table1.id > 1 500
    WHERE table2.id > %(clause_part)s
```

now if you look at this you'll see that in the doQuery function I never defined 'clause_part'.  this was defined in the myClause function but then never actually applied to the string as a replacement before the value was returned.

So then as a test i just put in another replacement string (the 'whatever') and now I can see how if you had some sort of array of tuples you could make a loop or whatnot and "recursively" replace all of them.

On the other hand, if you just wanted to solve the original actual problem I was facing (which was trying to figure out what the heck the query looked like) you could just to this instead:

```
print(cur._last_executed)
```

Sorry to waste all your time.  maybe someone will find this helpful.

Comment: I don't think you were wasting anyone's time. Thanks for self-answering. I believe you can accept your own answer soon. You'd be surprised who simple questions like this help! Anyway, glad I seem to have nudged you in the right direction.

Comment: You also may want to have a look at https://pyformat.info/ for more information on `str.format`. It's a little better suited to this named substitution you're doing than the older `%` formatting. Up to you if the trade-offs are worth rewriting. Cheers!

Comment: I'll check it out for learning purposes.  As this is not my code my goal is to change it as little as possible.  My only goal here is to optimize the query.   thanks again.